# Convert email body output to to TEXT file in PHP

Tags: php, email, base64, mime, rfc822

I want to convert the following email to a txt file using PHP script. im using pipe to mail function but getting gibberish when running the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
/* Read the message from STDIN */
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = ""; // This will be the variable holding the data.
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
/* Saves the data into a file */  
$fdw = fopen("/home/mrsirajali/pipemail.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
/* Script End */
?>
```

getting the following output

```
From ****@arbtradersignals.com Sun Mar 01 13:00:44 2015
Received: from [84.19.34.200] (port=54307 helo=wintest2)
    by **********.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with esmtpsa (TLSv1:AES256-SHA:256)
    (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <******@arbtradersignals.com>)
    id 1YSA2e-0002E3-Gc
    for *******@arbtradersignals.com; Sun, 01 Mar 2015 13:00:44 -0700
Message-ID: <c76708cf$20150301200044@wintest2>
User-Agent: MetaTrader 4 Terminal
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "=?UTF-8?B?RXhwZXJ0IEFkdmlzb3I=?="
 <*****@arbtradersignals.com>
To: "=?UTF-8?B?QXJidHJhZGVyIFNpZ25hbHM=?="
 <*****@arbtradersignals.com>
Subject: =?UTF8?B?QXJidHJhZGVyU2lnbmFscyBDVVJSRU5UIE9QRU4gUE9TSVRJT05TICAjU0lHMQ==?=
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

ClBhaXIgfCBEaXJlY3Rpb24gfCBFbnRyeSB8IFNMIHwgVFAKClVTREpQWSB8IEJVWSB8IDExOS40
MCB8IDExNy43NiB8IDEyMC40OApVU0RDSEYgfCBCVVkgfCAwLjk1MTMgfCAwLjkzNjUgfCAwLjk2
MDEKVVNEQ0FEIHwgQlVZIHwgMS4yNTAxIHwgMS4yMzAwIHwgMS4yNjQ0CkdCUEpQWSB8IEJVWSB8
IDE4My43MiB8IDE4Mi42MCB8IDE4Ni4wOApFVVJKUFkgfCBTRUxMIHwgMTM0LjUyIHwgMTM2LjIy
IHwgMTMyLjk5CgpUb3RhbCBPcGVuIFBvc2l0aW9ucyA9IDU=
```

content of original email .

**New pending orders**

Pair | Direction | Entry | SL | TP | Expiration

USDCHF | BUYSTOP | 0.9513 | 0.9365 | 0.9581 | 2015.02.26 23:59

USDCAD | BUYSTOP | 1.2501 | 1.2300 | 1.2638 | 2015.02.26 23:59

EURUSD | SELLSTOP | 1.1330 | 1.1488 | 1.1222 | 2015.02.26 23:59

EURJPY | SELLSTOP | 134.52 | 136.22 | 133.42 | 2015.02.26 23:59

*Total Pending Orders=4*

Comment: Okay you've told us what you want, but what's your actual question? You haven't told us what technology you're using, what you've tried so far or what went wrong. As it stands this reads like a request for some poor schmuck on the internet to do your work for you, you need a freelance programmer for that, not a Q&A site.

Comment: sure i will update  . apologies in advance for any vagueness

Answer (score 0):

That's not gibberish, that's the contents of the email.  If you want to decode the content-transfer-encoding, just feed the body to a `base64` decoder.  In the general case, you need (a library with) a good understanding of MIME structures.